# C# Winforms datagridview column header text

Tags: c#, excel, datagridview

I build this code which exports datagridview rows into Excel file

```
Excel.Application xlApp ;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
int i = 0;
int j = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= dgvInventory.RowCount - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j <= dgvInventory.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
    {
        DataGridViewCell cell = dgvInventory[j, i];
        xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 1, j + 1] = cell.Value;
    }
}

xlWorkBook.SaveAs(
    "D:\\exp.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue,
    misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue,
    misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue
);
xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
xlApp.Quit();

releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
releaseObject(xlApp);
```

it works good but problem is that im unable to export datagridview headertext. can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you post your code that worked to pass the datagridview header text to excel as well. I'm having the same issue and cant figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do a loop before your main loop, something like this:

```
    for (int j = 0; j <= this.dataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
    {
        string colName = dataGridView1.Columns[j].HeaderText;
    }
```

and set the header to excel worksheet row(0) or (1), column j to the value of colName.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Excel.Application xlApp ;
    Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook ;
    Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet ;
    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    xlApp = new Excel.ApplicationClass();
    xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add(misValue);
    xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    /*header text*/
    for (i = 0; i <= dgvInventory.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i+1] = dgvView.Columns[i].HeaderText; 
    }

    /*And the information of your data*/
    for (i = 0; i <= dgvInventory.RowCount - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j <= dgvInventory.ColumnCount - 1; j++)
        {
            DataGridViewCell cell = dgvInventory[j, i];
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = cell.Value;
        }
    }

    xlWorkBook.SaveAs(
        "D:\\exp.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue,misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);
    xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
    xlApp.Quit();

    releaseObject(xlWorkSheet);
    releaseObject(xlWorkBook);
    releaseObject(xlApp);
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)

Comment: oww sorry i only just copy his code and then paste this loop

Comment: /*header text*/
    for (i = 0; i <= dgvInventory.Columns.Count - 1; i++)
    {
      xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, i+1] = dgvView.Columns[i].HeaderText; 
    }

Comment: this loop which contains the header text that will help him to export datagridview headertext